# How to count common usage of items in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I want to count how much common projects companies have with each other, like:

| Company | Participation |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Project 1 |
| Microsoft | Project 1 |
| Tesla | Project 2 |
| Apple | Project 2 |
| Microsoft | Project 2 |

Is there a easy to go method in SQL to do so? With the output like that?

|  | Apple | Microsoft | Tesla |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Microsoft | 2 |  | 1 |
| Tesla | 1 | 1 |  |
| Apple |  | 2 | 1 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simple way, but - output isn't exactly as you'd want it to. It shows pairs and number of common projects (the `cnt` column):

```
SQL> select a.company, b.company, count(distinct b.participation) cnt
  2  from project a join project b on a.company < b.company
  3  group by a.company, b.company;

COMPANY   COMPANY          CNT
--------- --------- ----------
Apple     Tesla              1
Apple     Microsoft          2
Microsoft Tesla              1

SQL>
```

Comment: Its a powerful script but what is this? a.company < b.company

Comment: How a string can be greater then other strings?

Comment: It is used not as comparison, but not to join the same company from A and B tables (i.e. using it, you skip e.g. Apple vs. Apple or Tesla vs. Tesla) and to skip pairs you've already checked (i.e. if you have Apple - Tesla pair, you don't need Tesla - Apple once again).

Comment: Is there a term for this method a.company < b.company? I need to look it more deep. Never heard about it

Comment: That's a non-equi join.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do a self-join in the source query of a pivot.

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM (
>   SELECT t1.Company
>   , t2.Company AS Company2
>   , COUNT(t1.Participation) AS Participations
>   FROM CompanyProjectParticipations t1
>   JOIN CompanyProjectParticipations t2
>     ON t2.Participation = t1.Participation
>    AND t2.Company != t1.Company
>   GROUP BY t1.Company, t2.Company
> ) Src
> PIVOT (
>   SUM(Participations)
>   FOR Company2 IN ([Apple], [Microsoft], [Tesla])
> ) Pvt
> ORDER BY Company;
> ```

> | Company | Apple | Microsoft | Tesla |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Apple | *null* | 2 | 1 |
> | Microsoft | 2 | *null* | 1 |
> | Tesla | 1 | 1 | *null* |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=afe3600c6f3f51f5c66b98b715e1579d)*